# Android dialog box takes too much space

Tags: android, layout, android-tablelayout, row-height

Windows 7, Android Studio 1.1.0, compiled SDK 21, Samsung Galaxy Core (SDK 14).

I'm designing a form with few fields to fill as a dialog box, but I have plenty of blank space that I can't get rid of. Arranged it using TableLayout. I skipped some irrelevant fields in xml code, but all layout-related ones are there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
             android:background="@color/HellTeal"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView/>
        <EditText/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView/>
        <Spinner
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Spinner
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView/>
        <Spinner
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Everything looked fine on preview (sorry for this color, it's set to show taken space).

[image: Preview]

Unfortunately it looks different in reality. This takes way more space than it should, when I use it as dialog layout. Codes creating dialogs where maximally simplified, so it's not some weird declarations.  There are screens with this layout in AlertDialog and DialogFragment respectively. Notice, how additional space is colored in second case, weird.

[image: in Dialog]

I noticed that the amount of additional space somehow depends on contents. It's even posible for it to be equal to 0. See this comparison (I didn't change anything in either layout):

[image: Comprarison1]

I noticed that my layout appears properly if I don't set anything to views (onClickListeners, adapter etc.). So I started making as simplistic class as possible and adding proper line then. I found out that thing forcing this space in my case were spinners. Both use exactly the same array for items. I noticed the longer selected item is, the more aditional space is taken. Seems like maybe some mechanism preventing crossing screen borders, because right spinner affects dialog more. Left has to be like 7-8 characters to change dialog's size

[image: Comparison2]

What I tried:

- explicitly setting layout and rows to wrap_content
- using linear layouts as TableLayout and TableRow
- setting layout_height = "fill_parent" for TableLayout - I read on wrap_content messes things up, but not in this case
- Adding various views and observing, how amount of blank space changes, I see no formula
- simplifying code

Comment: That's wired. Can you post the java code where you create the dialog?

Comment: Updated question. Nothing uncommon I suppose.

Comment: yeah you are doing great. But I suggest you to try alertdialog. It solved my problems also. Check my answer below.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't use AlertDialog.Builder?

Comment: I made progress, please check out my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have everything that you need in your table layout even the ok and cancel buttons. I suggest you to go with AlertDialog. But don't set buttons and title in your builder. Set your view also after created the alert. Try following code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//you won't need yes no buttons because it is already containing in your layout
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.aaa_test, null);
AlertDialog aler=builder.create();
alert.setView(view,0,0,0,0);
alert.show();
```

Comment: Nope, additional space is still there. Also, I don't think getting AlertDialog to call setView() changes anything, because this method is called by AlertDialog.Builder (it's delegated).

Comment: @MaciejDziuban I can't figure out why it didn't work. Because it suppose show only the layout that you created but not the title and yes no buttons. Actually I'm using it in my apps. However glad you could make it.

Comment: Oh, if you mean those new screens with red background, it's another case. I'd tried not defining buttons, as you advised, but then i got layout+empty space (without buttons).